# Wrong values in gnome-system-monitor after a partition resizing

Tags: partition, gnome-system-monitor

Recently i've resized my root partition to increment the swap. After the process, gnome-system-monitor doesn't recognize the new status of my partitions, but `fdisk` shows the updated table whit correct values. I rebooted several times but nothing has changed. Here some screenshot:

[image: "fdisk -l" output]

[image: swap dimension]

[image: sda partitions]

Comment: Thanks to your help now i have the correct value for the swap. Through GParted i've re-mount the swap after a formatting, now i have only some incongruences with sda values between gnome-system-monitor and fdisk, how can i solve that? I mean, i cannot format sda, do i? Actually it can be different approximations of sda amount between programs, so it could not be really an issue

Comment: Most likely different units. 1 MiB = 1024 * 1024 bytes = 1.048576 MB (and of course some things say MB or just M, when they are using MiB-style units).  MiB is how most hardware works, but it doesn't match the original SI standard units used in other areas, so it's all a bit of a mess.  E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte#History_and_usage

Answer (score 0):

Likely you need to reformat the swap partition (remember to deactivate it first!)

Resizing the partition in fdisk doesn't modify the header of the swap/filesystem/whatever.